# Limit array values based on interface used as return

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```js
export interface StoreCursor {
    created: Date;
    id: number;
}

export default class PageUtil {
    public static decode<T>(cursor?: string, dates?: (keyof T)[]): T | undefined {
        if (!cursor) {
            return;
        }

        const json = Buffer.from(cursor, "base64").toString("utf8");

        return JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => (dates?.includes(key) ? new Date(value) : value));
    }
}

const decoded = PageUtil.decode<StoreCursor>(cursor, ["created"]);
```

But I get next error, and I don't know how solve it:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof T'.

I've also tried:

```js
public static decode<T>(cursor?: string, dates?: (keyof T & string)[]): T | undefined {
    [...]
}
```

But the error is similar:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof T & string'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.

I want `dates` to be limited to keys of `StoreCursor` (or better, only to keys of `StoreCursor` of type `Date`).

Comment: I guess it's complaining correctly, because as your type T you're passing StoreCursor, that doesn't contains any parameter of type string, whereas inside your decode() first param is of type string. So you need to make you Generic Type compatible with your function args.

Comment: Yeah, but I am trying to refer to the keys of `StoreCursor` (`created` or `id`) not to their values. I also have tried `export interface TattooStoreCursor extends Record<string, unknown> { [...] }` but the error is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key parameter of the callback to `JSON` is typed as `string`, while your array has items of type `keyof T`. `includes` expects an element of the same type as the item in the array and there is no way to express in TS something like `If it's a literal type or a key type, accept the base type (in this case string)`.

You have one of two options:

First just assert `key` is `keyof T` it might not be, but that is what you are testing so no runtime issue can come from the assertion:

```
export default class PageUtil {
    public static decode<T>(cursor?: string, dates?: (keyof T)[]): T | undefined {
        if (!cursor) {
            return;
        }

        const json = "";

        return JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => (dates?.includes(key as keyof T) ? new Date(value) : value));
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6&ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeBYAUPEfAJYB2ALiDAGZRgICCMMUAngDwAqAfDgcUGkykAK6gAzgAoUALnhcAlPLQoUEEFDIDiAXwL78IAB4AHFDArCqteggDKFCyADComBIv9CxMHChUwPIAIgEgANw6RCRB8GSiALZo1JH4hgQm5pbwoHSiEFaQUBIS8AAKUIggAKoUJFh4PkSmomgQJGDwEhQBHTngKKDcPFJg7p4wAPzy3TDkiAA0OWES0-BSANYgbCg0CooA2gC6ygrwAD7womS55CDA3kLEJHtSAIRjHhaKj09CcBR3GRUn94OkmkIwCgyN14AArTxkeAAXngACI0akov8QICYEiAFL2ADyADkAHSmWASEBSBHQpabbZLABumFEIB+yL4UmAK0m5PIYkkTLY8GK8C2Oz2SngkziIAA7vBQlQpGyIByfvINVrFCC9AYCKAinB4GyYPBPhMZhQ5mREKkoTCrCbBvcUeVKjU6hByW6ho5nG4vjARtaLEsDmi-JpAmiTuEgA)

Or another option is to use a separate implementation signature in which `dates` is of type `string[]`

```
export default class PageUtil {
    public static decode<T>(cursor?: string, dates?: (keyof T)[]): T | undefined
    public static decode(cursor?: string, dates?: string[]): any {
        if (!cursor) {
            return;
        }

        const json = "";

        return JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => (dates?.includes(key) ? new Date(value) : value));
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6&ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeBYAUPEfAJYB2ALiDAGZRgICCMMUAngDwAqAfDgcUGkykAK6gAzgAoUALnhcAlPLQoUEEFDIDiAXwL78IAB4AHFDArCqteggDKFCyADComBIv9CxMHChUwPIAIgEgANw6RCRB8GSiALZo1JH4hgQm5pbwoHSiEFaQUBIS8AAKUIggAKoUJFh4PkSmomgQJGDwEhQBHTngKKDcPFJg7p4wAPzy3TDkiAA0OWES0-BSANYgbCg0CooA2gC6ygrwAD7womS55CDAUfAtbX3dvZ2gYIMgo+MWa7N5ktgCsARQ5mREMdTlo2N4hMQSHspABCMYeCyKeEIoRwCjuMipHHwdJNIRfMjdeAAK08ZHgAF54AAiZmpR6CPEE+AAKXsAHkAHIAOlMsAkP1pKDIS022yWADdMKIQFiGXwpCCqKtheQxJI5WwsZM4iAAO7wUJUKRKiAqrHyW32xREvQGAifaBweBKmDwdETGbg+apClUz7fYCM8qVGp1CDCiNDRzONwYmAjAMWJYHZl+TSBZkncJAA)

Comment: I have opted by the first solution, seems me more clear. Thanks you.